# Save a matplotlib from a custom function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to follow this [tutorial](http://nicolasfauchereau.github.io/climatecode/posts/drawing-a-gauge-with-matplotlib/) to make a gauge plot but it doesn't seem to have how to save the plot. I am wondering how to save this gauge matplotlib.

Comment: Check the last line, it's clearly illustrated as `fig.savefig(fname, dpi=200)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial you linked, does mention how to save the plot

in function `gauge`

```
def gauge(labels=['LOW','MEDIUM','HIGH','VERY HIGH','EXTREME'],
          colors='jet_r', arrow=1, title='', fname=False):
```

There is an attribute `fname`. If you set a path to `fname` it will store your gauge as the given name.

For example

```
gauge(labels=['LOW','MEDIUM','HIGH','VERY HIGH','EXTREME','CRITICAL'],
      colors='YlOrRd_r', arrow=3, title='drought severity index',fname='gauge.png')
```